# Adding spaces in multiple lines simultaneously - in Pycharm

Tags: formatting, indentation, pycharm, spaces

I occasionally need to go line-by line and change the indentation of the code.

Is there a shortcut in Pycharm where I can add spaces (format the indent) in the begining of multiple lines simultaneously without processing each line individually?

Answer (score 86):

Highlight/ select the lines you want indented, then press `TAB` as often as needed until they reach the proper indent level.

You can remove spaces with `SHIFT TAB`.

You can also use `CTRL+ALT+I` to auto-indent the selection.

Comment: But what if the TAB makes 8 spaces instead of 4 which is what intended? Is there anyway to force it to move forward only by 4 spaces?

Comment: @Allan Tab Size is a setting under Settings -> Code Style -> the language you are using

Comment: ctrl+alt+i is possibly the most useful keyboard shortcut I've ever learned.

Comment: ctrl+alt+i doesn't work on my Windows machine, but TAB does.

Comment: What if you want to add spaces that don't end up like CTRL + ALT + I ends up? as in if CTRL ALT I adds three spaces and I wanna add 4?

Comment: Go to tools and disable Vim emulator.

Answer (score 18):

Select the block that you want to indent then press  `TAB`. It will work.

Answer (score 4):

To auto indent all the codes in Pycharm just press these sequencies:

> CTR + A to select all the text files and then press
>
> CTRL+ALT+I

Comment: What if you want to add spaces that don't end up like CTRL + ALT + I ends up? as in if CTRL ALT I adds three spaces and I wanna add 4?

Answer (score 0):

Select all that you want to indent, then do CTRL+ALT+I to indent all of it. This should work in Pycharm

Comment: What if you want to add spaces that don't end up like CTRL + ALT + I ends up? as in if CTRL ALT I adds three spaces and I wanna add 4?

Answer (score 0):

Use shift +alt on windows machine

Answer (score 0):

Continuation indent for Mac pro: Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style -> the language -> Tabs and Indents

Answer (score 0):

If `Ctrl + ALT + I` is not working and every time needs to press the Insert button to get the pointer.

So go to `Tools -> Select Vim` if it is checked then it will be disabled.

Now you can intend code directly selecting multiple lines.